# How to Pin Phone Number Dial on Start

Tags: pin-to-start

Is there any way to pin phone number dial on start? (It should look like windows icon>dial phone number icon>dial number>call)

Comment: Have you tried Easy Dial from Tagtual?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot currently have a one-tap speed dial direct from the start screen.  This is possibly by design to prevent accidental calls.

However, you can pin a particular contact to the start screen and then it's tap to open, tap to dial.

Windows Phone 8.1 has a speed dial section on the Phone app.  There you can group and arrange all your commonly called numbers for one-tap access.

[Windows Phone Central Forums - How does Speed Dial work on my 8.1 phone?](http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8-1-guides-how-tos/279765-how-does-speed-dial-work-my-8-1-phone.html)